# PrimeFaces pickList

Tags: exception, primefaces, picklist

Is it necessary to use a converter when working with `pickList`? Well, here's my code:

```
<p:pickList value="#{usuarioBean.listaMembros}" var="#{usuario}" itemLabel="#{usuario.nome}">
  <f:facet name="cadastrados">Membros</f:facet>
  <f:facet name="equipe">Membros da Equipe</f:facet>
</p:pickList>
```

All I keep getting is:

> java.util.ArrayList cannot be cast to org.primefaces.model.DualListModel

Answer (score 5):

Your picklist needs to point to a DualListModel...which itself contains a source list and a target list. So you need to create a source list and a target list and then create a DualListModel from them e.g. taking the primefaces showcase example:

```
        List<Player> source = new ArrayList<Player>();  
        List<Player> target = new ArrayList<Player>();  

        source.add(new Player("Messi", 10, "messi.jpg"));  
        source.add(new Player("Iniesta", 8, "iniesta.jpg"));  
        source.add(new Player("Villa", 7, "villa.jpg"));  
        source.add(new Player("Alves", 2, "alves.jpg"));  
        source.add(new Player("Xavi", 6, "xavi.jpg"));  
        source.add(new Player("Puyol", 5, "puyol.jpg"));      

        listaMembros = new DualListModel<Player>(source, target);
```

Then your getter and setter would get and set a DualListModel...e.g

```
public DualListModel<Player> getListaMembros() {  
        return listaMembros;  
    }  
    public void setPlayers(DualListModel<Player> players) {  
        this.listaMembros = listaMembros;  
    }
```

Then in your xhtml the value of your picklist would be

> `#{usarioBean.listaMembros}`

If your data within your lists is a complex type then you'll need to use a converter to convert the object